# Source Install Fails with "No package vtk-phython available"

Tags: ros, desktop-full, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do a source install of Jade onto Fedora 22, using the instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source). I am trying the desktop-full install. Everything works until I try to resolve the dependencies with the command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y
```

I then get an error that `No package vtk-pHython available`. I assume this should be `vtk-python`? if so, who should I report the error to? The full console output is below.

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y

executing command [sudo -H dnf --assumeyes install collada-dom-devel python-matplotlib PyQwt-devel gtk2-devel tinyxml-devel PyQt4 yaml-cpp-devel python-nose pcl-devel opencv-devel ogre-devel libuuid-devel console-bridge-devel sbcl tango-icon-theme cmake cppunit-devel libcurl-devel bzip2-devel pcl-tools python-devel mesa-libGL-devel urdfdom-devel apr-devel vtk-phython vtk-java pcl wxPython-devel qhull-devel numpy urdfdom-headers-devel python-mock boost-devel PyOpenGL log4cxx-devel python-empy PyQt4-devel libtool-ltdl-devel libtheora-devel assimp libtool hddtemp gtest-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel graphviz fltk-devel poco-devel gazebo-devel eigen3-devel python-psutil libogg-devel qt-devel pydot python-pygraphviz lz4-devel python-pillow-qt python-netifaces opencv-python sip-devel mesa-libGLU-devel assimp-devel]

Last metadata expiration check performed 0:02:40 ago on Tue Nov  3 14:10:22 2015.

No package vtk-phython available.

Error: Unable to find a match.

ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install

  dnf: command [sudo -H dnf --assumeyes install collada-dom-devel python-matplotlib PyQwt-devel gtk2-devel tinyxml-devel PyQt4 yaml-cpp-devel python-nose pcl-devel opencv-devel ogre-devel libuuid-devel console-bridge-devel sbcl tango-icon-theme cmake cppunit-devel libcurl-devel bzip2-devel pcl-tools python-devel mesa-libGL-devel urdfdom-devel apr-devel vtk-phython vtk-java pcl wxPython-devel qhull-devel numpy urdfdom-headers-devel python-mock boost-devel PyOpenGL log4cxx-devel python-empy PyQt4-devel libtool-ltdl-devel libtheora-devel assimp libtool hddtemp gtest-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel graphviz fltk-devel poco-devel gazebo-devel eigen3-devel python-psutil libogg-devel qt-devel pydot python-pygraphviz lz4-devel python-pillow-qt python-netifaces opencv-python sip-devel mesa-libGLU-devel assimp-devel] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220387/source-install-fails-with-%22no-package-vtk-phython-available%22/) by [danthony](https://answers.ros.org/users/23354/danthony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree that this definitely looks like a typo. The mistake can be seen [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/76cc22565c0b302c908f1a03cd7a6c58030fce00/rosdep/base.yaml#L2927-L2929). The [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues) package is where you would want to submit a bug report.

Assuming that the `vtk-python` package will actually provide the necessary libs/headers/modules/etc. needed for the `python-vtk` dependency (it probably will), you could continue with your install by commenting out this dependency in any of the `package.xml` files in your `~/ros_catkin_ws/src/` directory.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1